# How to decrypt the text using Base64 encoding scheme algorithm

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have created code which takes a string from a text field and calls a encrypting method for doing encryption of that text using the base64 encoding scheme. But I don't have any idea how to create the decryption method for decrypting whatever value I am getting from the  method.

Comment: Base64 is a method of transmitting data, but it's certainly not "encryption".  Just make sure you're hashing any passwords first, please.

Comment: Dear sir,would you please give me some example or demo regarding encryption i googled a lot but not found a good example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save yourself some trouble and [download](http://projectswithlove.com/projects/NSData_Base64.zip) the NSData Base64 category.

Then you can encode or decode using a single line.